# Qt Creator build project - No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, qgis

Sorry to being a noob, but I just moved from Window, Eclipse and Java to OpenSUSE, C++ and Qt Creator, and I met a problem. I am working to create a QGIS application, I have the *.h files in /usr/include/gqis, and *.so files in /usr/lib. I added this line

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/qgis
```

at the end of .pro file of project so I can include QGIS library. So far as I coded, everything went smoothly, but when I built the project, Qt Creator threw an error:

```
qgis.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/qgis/qgsapplication.h
```

and it mapped to line 4:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <qgis/qgsvectorlayer.h>
#include <qgis/qgsapplication.h>
#include <qgis/qgsproviderregistry.h>
#include <qgis/qgssinglesymbolrenderer.h>
#include <qgis/qgsmaplayerregistry.h>
#include <qgis/qgsvectorlayer.h>
#include <qgis/qgsmapcanvas.h>
```

As far as I searched, I am still unable to solve this problem. Please can anyone help me?

Comment: I have the *.h files in /usr/include/gqis or qgis ???

Comment: Sorry, a typo. Of course it is in /usr/include/qgis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/qgis
```

and

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <qgsvectorlayer.h>
#include <qgsapplication.h>
#include <qgsproviderregistry.h>
#include <qgssinglesymbolrenderer.h>
#include <qgsmaplayerregistry.h>
#include <qgsvectorlayer.h>
#include <qgsmapcanvas.h>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try just:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/
```

Afterall, the `qgis` is already listed in the `#include <qgis/...>` path.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, but anyway thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a windows Machine. I'm not sure why this is the case but if you put your project in a shallow directory, the problem might go away. Instead of something like **C:\Projects\C++\IntroToDesignPatterns2012\Chapter13\objectBrowser02\objectBrowser02**
Try something simple like **C:\Projects\objectBrowser02**